# Flutter signin Google Play Games error status code: 12501

Tags: flutter, google-play-games

I have an application developed at Ionic js and I decided to learn how to develop the same application with Flutter.

I'm just struggling a bit to connect with Google Play Games.

My question about the SHA1 hashes, I would like help for each of them, we have 3 hashes: 1 debug, 1 release and 1 from Google Play itself that signs the application before publishing it.

In firebase, which of these hashes do I use? On the Google console, which of these hashes do I use?

A complete tutorial would help a lot, because the ones I'm following, talk about parts and not about their complexity, explaining all the steps since before publication.

Comment: Did you solved the problem bro?

Comment: Yes, in firebase, add two hashes... debug and google sign hash

Answer (score 1):

If app_id is defined as below, change it

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="xxxxxxxxxxx" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Change

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

res/values/id.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_id">xxxxxxxx</string>

<string name="achievement_prime">YOUR_ACHIEVEMENT_PRIME_ID</string>
<string name="achievement_really_bored">YOUR_ACHIEVEMENT_REALLY_BORED_ID</string>
<string name="achievement_bored">YOUR_ACHIEVEMENT_BORED_ID</string>
<string name="achievement_humble">YOUR_ACHIEVEMENT_HUMBLE_ID</string>
<string name="achievement_arrogant">YOUR_ACHIEVEMENT_ARROGANT_ID</string>
<string name="achievement_leet">YOUR_ACHIEVEMENT_LEET_ID</string>

<string name="leaderboard_easy">YOUR_LEADERBOARD_EASY_ID</string>
<string name="leaderboard_hard">YOUR_LEADERBOARD_HARD_ID</string>

<string name="event_start">YOUR_EVENT_START</string>
<string name="event_number_chosen">YOUR_EVENT_NUMBER_CHOSEN</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, several days tries, only your piece of advice helps me.