# Flutter loader stuck. PlatformException(failed_to_authenticate, SIGN_IN_REQUIRED)

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication

I have developed a game using "games_services" package. Everything works fine if I launch it from my ide in debug and release mode on my android phone. After I upload it to internal or closed testing, I download it from the play store and I get this error:

> PlatformException(failed_to_authenticate, statusCode:
> SIGN_IN_REQUIRED).

[image]

I tried to use another package with firebase integration but still the same problem.
I followed all the steps from google documentation and my project is ready to be published to the production but I encounter this error. I spent 2 days trying to figure it out by myself.
On iOS ..there are no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following things:

**1. Add the testers not only on internal test, but also on Play Console > Your game > Google Play services > Config > Testers**
2. [You have made this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60020922/flutter-signin-google-play-games-error-status-code-12501) (but instead of `id.xml` name the file `strings.xml`)
3. The project ID is correct in `strings.xml` (you can see the project ID on Play Console)